# Why does display:inline affect children using position:sticky?

Tags: html, css

It was my understanding, that if an element with `position:sticky` is nested within a parent element: when the parent leaves the viewport, that "sticky" element will leave with it.

Here I have a "sticky" `<ul>` within a `<nav>` within `<main>`. When scrolling through the main element, when the `<nav>` would normally scroll off-screen, it instead behaves as if *it's* become `position:sticky`. However, if I change the `display` of the `<nav>` to be either `block` or `inline-block`, it behaves as I thought that it would. What's happening here?

```css
body {
  border: 2px dotted gray;
  padding: 2rem;
}

nav {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px dotted gray;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <h1>Main Heading</h1>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis enim ipsum. Quisque vel lacinia urna. Aenean et cursus nisi. Mauris eleifend fermentum elit, id finibus sem varius id. Duis imperdiet massa at velit ultrices gravida id sit amet ipsum. Praesent convallis quis metus nec dignissim. Etiam et odio id odio tincidunt bibendum quis vel urna. Cras ultricies diam eget nisl posuere, vel mollis sapien venenatis. Nulla eu diam hendrerit, gravida dolor vitae, cursus nulla.</p>
      <p>Maecenas vulputate viverra diam elementum volutpat. Sed vulputate ac velit et tincidunt. Mauris eget nisl ut mauris eleifend accumsan. Phasellus accumsan ultricies leo, vitae gravida tellus rutrum sed. Proin condimentum pulvinar rhoncus. Duis quis massa ligula. Cras ac est aliquet, facilisis leo nec, scelerisque arcu. Nunc ultricies sollicitudin semper. Nulla varius laoreet posuere. Suspendisse hendrerit nulla id mi rhoncus iaculis. Donec interdum ultricies risus, eget malesuada justo pellentesque placerat. Cras convallis eget dolor in tempus. Ut imperdiet tellus eu nibh bibendum rutrum.</p>
      <p>Integer eros purus, porta non rhoncus a, accumsan et lectus. Ut a ullamcorper purus. Proin mattis fermentum lorem varius mollis. Nullam imperdiet, neque auctor sodales molestie, nulla enim suscipit leo, id cursus nibh quam vel neque. Curabitur mauris nunc, varius id pharetra sed, elementum nec tellus. Morbi luctus auctor egestas. Cras accumsan arcu ullamcorper porttitor imperdiet. Sed semper magna nec nibh venenatis, sed laoreet neque malesuada. Aenean sit amet erat molestie, efficitur lacus vitae, laoreet lectus. Proin elit enim, ultrices nec nibh eget, vehicula maximus odio. Nunc egestas dapibus porta. Mauris aliquet bibendum ultrices.</p>
      <p>Praesent efficitur sit amet magna bibendum bibendum. In convallis nisl aliquam vulputate gravida. Praesent ornare pretium dapibus. Aliquam malesuada in metus eget eleifend. Morbi at cursus augue, sed sagittis dolor. Pellentesque facilisis urna metus, et maximus risus tristique et. Cras blandit condimentum pulvinar. Fusce mattis egestas tortor, ut aliquam libero ultrices eu. Praesent mauris enim, egestas id tristique in, mollis in tellus. Integer tristique augue quis lorem facilisis, non convallis lorem consequat. Morbi sagittis at mi ac finibus. Vivamus eget diam nec quam lobortis viverra. Morbi viverra ut odio non vehicula.</p>
      <p>Proin faucibus tortor quis nisl placerat, eget commodo ante iaculis. Proin quis aliquam ante, a iaculis nisi. Vivamus porta mi et neque ullamcorper mattis. Suspendisse cursus, urna et placerat posuere, risus arcu tempor nunc, eget hendrerit nulla ex maximus ante. Morbi elit mauris, vestibulum vel elementum et, mattis non quam. Quisque aliquet congue quam, id dictum nunc scelerisque in. Mauris ipsum risus, vestibulum venenatis lorem vitae, porta semper ante. Aliquam eu velit vitae neque iaculis vestibulum id a magna. Integer malesuada at lacus ac vulputate.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: I am not sure where you read about sticky position, but as per https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, it seems its different.

Comment: @kiner_shah In their example HTML, if you wrap their div with class `sticky`, such that it's within another div (e.g. `<div><div class="sticky">I am sticky!</div></div>`, it will stop behaving as if it's position sticky. If you then add `display:inline` to that wrapper div, it'll behave as if it's position sticky again, but the parent "wrapper div" is also moving down the page with it. You can do this multiple times, as long as all of the parents are `display:inline`, but if a single one is `display:block` or `inline-block` it will stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about "containing block". sticky position doesn't consider the parent element but consider its containing block which is the parent element in most of the cases but in your case it's not because:

> For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the content edge of **the nearest ancestor box that is a block container** or which establishes a formatting context. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html)</sup>

`sticky` is not mentioned there but it behave the same as `relative` and `static` (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#def-cb)

If you check the definition of sticky you can read:

> Identical to relative, except that its offsets are automatically adjusted in reference to the nearest ancestor scroll container’s scrollport (as modified by the inset properties) in whichever axes the inset properties are not both auto, to **try to keep the box in view within its containing block** as the user scrolls. This positioning scheme is called sticky positioning. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#position-property)</sup>

So the containing block in your case is no more `nav` but `main`

Comment: Ahh thank you. I was sure I read the "parent element" somewhere & found on the MDN that their nomenclature might have tripped me up. *"A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed **until it reaches the boundary of its parent**,"* but earlier up the page states: *"sticky - The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its **nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block...**"* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position